# Read input files on the fly in Spark

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

So, my program reads input files from a folder. Those input files are zipped, so that they are given to only one map task. Is it possible to fill the input folder on the fly, so that as the zip files are being uploaded to the input folder, a map task is assigned to each new zip file. And when all zip files are finaly uploaded to the input folder, also signal that the input folder is now full. In this way, I don't have to wait for the input folder to be full before running my spark program.

P.S: I don't want to use any streaming framework for this. But if that is the only possible option, do let me know.

Comment: do you want to start a spark cluster only when there are input files or the spark cluster can remain always alive?

Comment: By "on the fly" do you mean reading the partially created files as they are being created ?

Comment: I do not believe you can do this without Spark Streaming, and why not use Spark Streaming?